# How to have retry decorator indicate used all retries?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have implemented the retry decorator in my code, but would like to somehow indicate when it has used all of its retries.  How can I do this?

I am using [retrying decorator](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/) v1.3.3.

I tried using stop_func, but this seems to be called in nominal behaviour, not on a retry.

I am not sure how to call out the attempt number from the decorator.

```
from retrying import retry

def _query_with_retries(self):
    _retriable_query = retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3,
                             wait_incrementing_start=50,
                             wait_incrementing_increment=10)(self._query)
    return _retriable_query()
```

Currently, my code just throws a generic exception on the last retry.  I would like to be able to message "all retries have been used up" or something like that.

Comment: `try: return_retriable_query(); except SomeException: print('all retries have been used up')`?

Comment: @Idlehands that does what I wanted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the `retrying.RetryError` exception that is raised when the decorator stops retrying; do so in your own wrapper decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
from retrying import retry, RetryError

def printing_retry(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(f):            
        decorated = retry(*args, **kwargs)(f)
        @wraps(decorated)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return decorated(*args, **kwargs)
            except RetryError:
                print("All retries have been used up")
                # optionally, re-raise the exception at this point
                # raise
        return wrapper
    if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
        return decorator(args[0])
    return decorator
```

This decorator would replace the `@retry` decorators in your code; when you call a decorated function, it'll catch the `RetryError` exception that is raised when the function has run out of attempts, and print out a message instead.

Do remember to set `wrap_exception=True` if you want to wrap any exceptions raised during retrying in a `RetryException` exception.

Demo:

```
>>> @printing_retry(stop_max_attempt_number=1, wrap_exception=True)
... def do_something_unreliable():
...     if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
...         raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
...     else:
...         return "Awesome sauce!"
...
>>> do_something_unreliable()
All retries have been used up
>>> do_something_unreliable()
'Awesome sauce!'
```

Comment: Initially, it wasn't working for me. Then I realized I forgot to include wrap_exception=True.  With that, this works great!  Thanks Martijn!